# How can I use System Environment Variables in Angularjs Protractor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, protractor

My plan is to store a username and password as system environment variables and reference them in an Angularjs Protractor config file. I defined the variables in `/etc/environment`. This is what I've tried so far:

```
params: {
  login: {
    user: $E2E_USER,
    pass: $E2E_PASS
  }
}
```

I also tried this:

```
params: {
  login: {
    user: process.env.E2E_USER,
    pass: process.env.E2E_PASS
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I simulated your second approach (also used in https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/ciConf.js) and it worked fine – which error do you encounter using `process.env.E2E_USER` etc.?

Comment: You can also fire up the `node` command line and check the list that `console.log(process.env)`gives you – see if `E2E_USER` and `E2E_PASS` really are present in your environment.

Comment: `process.env.E2E_USER` is `undefiend`. When I print `process.env`, I don't see `E2E_USER` in the list. I defined the variable in `/etc/environment`, should it be somewhere else? Thanks!

Comment: I would have gone with the `export` way you found yourself. All good :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used `export E2E_USER=username` and that worked.

Comment: Might I clarify: `process.env.E2E_USER` works. The `export` command in this answer merely sets the environment variable E2E_USER. I presume when the OP asked the question, the variable wasn't set.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `process.env.YOUR_ENV` in NodeJS, so for example inside onPrepare function, not directly inside params:

```
exports.config = {
    onPrepare: function() {
        //load env variables for testing
        if (typeof process.env.URL !== "undefined") {
            browser.baseUrl = process.env.URL;
            console.log('Base URL = ' +process.env.URL);
        }
},
params: { ...
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same with angular2 and protractor, but no luck. When i console log `process.env`, i do not see any of the environment variables. How can i fix my issue??

Comment: Directly inside `params` works fine for me, though Angular 13, not AngularJS.